# limit of a recursive sequence, Am I allowed to divide by $b_n^2$?

Tags: calculus, limits, recurrence-relations

$$b_1 > 0$$
$${b_{n + 1}} = {{{b_n}^2 + 1} \over {{b_n}}} = {{{{{b_n}^2} \over {{b_n}^2}} + {1 \over {{b_n}^2}}} \over {{{{b_n}} \over {{b_n}^2}}}}\mathop = {{1 + {1 \over {{b_n}^2}}} \over {{1 \over {{b_n}^{}}}}} = {1 \over {{1 \over {{b_n}^{}}}}} + {{{1 \over {{b_n}^2}}} \over {{1 \over {{b_n}^{}}}}} = {b_n} + {1 \over {{b_n}^{}}} =  + \infty $$

Is it right?

Comment: You have already assumed $b_n\to\infty$

Comment: How exactly? I need to prove it anyhow..

Comment: you have written $$\frac1{b_n}=0,$$ right?

Comment: Oh I see.. So my way is wrong. What would be your approach?

Comment: The tag ([tag:limit-theorems]) is intended for questions about limit theorems in probability theory and not for questions about determining limits of sequences or functions, see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/limit-theorems/info) and the tag-excerpt. (The tag-excerpt is also shown when you are adding a tag to a question.)